# How to add a TextView that occupies the full width of the phone's layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm working on an app where I want to have a progress bar and a text view. And the thing is the text view should have a different background. When I use `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, it leaves space on the sides of the textview. When we have a white background, it is okay but when we are putting a different background, it doesn't look good. How can I achieve this?

In short, I'm getting the following view(first image) when I put `match_parent` but I want the page to look like the one in the second image.

[image: When I add match_parent] [image: This is how I want the UI to be]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="senti.com.freelaneprogress.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="40"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eta"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1.3in"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2in"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/textviewbg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30pt"
        android:contextClickable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Delete the default padding form the main container (RelativeLayout) that the IDE adds when you create the Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the paddingLeft, paddingRight and paddingBottom to 0dp for the RelativeLayout view. In other words,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="senti.com.freelaneprogress.MainActivity">


    ...
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the minimum you need to achieve your desired result. But if you want to be absolute, you can set the RelativeLayout's paddingTop to 0dp too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

the textview is matching is parent. The thing is, the parent is not matching the whole parent view because of the padding.
Try to remove the padding, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the padding of the relative layout. And if you really want you can give it to progressbar.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="senti.com.freelaneprogress.MainActivity">
```

Setting padding to relative gives the container space which you don't want